# Header in mobile version of elementor doesn´t change

Tags: header, elementor

I have a problem with changing header in elementor. When I want to change location of my button or site logo in mobile version in elementor header template nothing happens. Only when I move the button from desktop in elementor it changes on mobile too but that makes my desktop version look bad. Somebody please help I will be really grateful for any ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 2 different sections 1 for desktop and 1 for mobile. Hide mobile version for desktop and desktop version for mobile. You can apply different styles for both desktop and mobile but for the change of positions of elements you need to use different sections. You can check the following screenshot. The top one for mobile header and bottom one for the desktop header.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGjth.png)